# what's a word/phrase that describes unwillingness to share advice (such as strategy on how to improve in a sports match)?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm having trouble coming up with a word/two-word phrase describing unwillingness to share advice (such as strategy on how to improve in a sports match)? May someone help?

I'm hoping that this would either be one word or two words.

Comment: If I weren't naturally *reticent*, I might be willing to share the answer with you.

Answer (score 3):

**Uncooperative**

> unwilling to help others or do what they ask.

Comment: I had not seen your answer yet, when writing mine ; it seems to me that the question is not about somebody refusing to help, but to listen.

Comment: sorry about the misunderstanding.  I was hoping for a phrase describing someone refusing to help, not listen.

Answer (score 2):

**Close-lipped** [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/closelipped):

> inclined to secrecy or reticence about divulging information;
>    "although they knew her whereabouts her friends kept close about it"

Answer (score 1):

Secretive; uninformative; obfuscatory (though the latter would mean they're deliberately clouding the picture). Can't think of anything that's exactly what you want though.

Answer (score 0):

stubborn, obstinate, headstrong, pig-headed, mulish, dogged, adamant, inflexible, uncompromising, unbending, unyielding, obdurate, intractable, refractory, recalcitrant, contumacious, and, in UK, unmalleable

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'to keep your cards close to your chest' means to keep information from others. Someone who likes to have all the information.
Not a handy single word that i know of unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A person displaying an unwillingness to share (a strategy or tactic) may be described as "guarded" or "unrevealing" in a sense.